# Magic Number for secure file upload

Tags: php, file, security, file-upload

1. Is Magic-Number check a good idea to verify a file or is another way better.
2. This my function idea to check the Magic-Number of `$_FILES['tmp_name']` but on this point the file is load to temp folder on server. Can't I check it in the same time it is stream to the server so i can't abort the loading to the temp, before it is completely loaded.

```
// check file type with the first bit of magic numbers
function is_magic_number_ok($file)
{

    switch ($this->extension) {
        case '.ai':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '25504446',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 4,
            );
            break;
        case '.bmp':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '424D',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 2,
            );
            break;
        case '.class':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => 'CAFEBABE',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 4,
            );
            break;
        case '.jpg':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => 'FFD8',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 2,
            );
            break;
        case '.jp2':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '0000000C6A5020200D0A',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 10,
            );
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '47494638',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 4,
            );
            break;
        case '.tif':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '4949',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 2,
            );
            break;
        case '.png':
            $magic_option = array(
                'magic_number_hex'        => '89504E47',
                'magic_number_bit_length' => 4,
            );
            break;
        default:
            return false;

    }

    // get the bit limited file length and convert to HEX
    $file_bin_stream = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, 0, $magic_option['magic_number_bit_length']);

    $file_hex = strtoupper(bin2hex($file_bin_stream));

    if ($magic_option['magic_number_hex'] == $file_hex) {
        echo 'true';
        return true;
    } else {
        echo 'false';
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: May I ask what is your scenario here? Are you trying to figure out whether file was not modified in transit?

Comment: The scenario is a secure file upload function to save my server from bad uploads.  i now this is not the owen way to hack the system but i want learn more php securety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Its not a bad idea, but it doesn't always work. Some file types don't correctly use magic numbers.
2. You would have to do something in the web server to do that. PHP code doesn't execute until the file has already been uploaded.

Lastly, php has a built in file info extension that will do most of this for you. More info: http://php.net/fileinfo